# Webpack Vuejs Compile scss error

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I have this webpack.config:

```
{
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['css-loader']
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.*(sass|scss)$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        })
      },
```

And in my main.js I do:

```
require('./style/_variables.scss');
```

but it return this error:

> Invalid CSS after "...load the styles": expected 1 selector or
>   at-rule, was "var content = requi"
>             in /var/www/html/site/src/style/_variables.scss (line 1, column 1)
>           at runLoaders (/var/www/html/site/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:195:19)
>           at /var/www/html/site/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:364:11
>           at /var/www/html/site/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:230:18
>           at context.callback (/var/www/html/site/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
>           at Object.asyncSassJobQueue.push [as callback] (/var/www/html/site/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:55:13)
>           at Object. (/var/www/html/site /node_modules/async/dist/async.js:2244:31)
>           at Object.callback (/var/www/html/site/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:906:16)
>           at options.error (/var/www/html/site/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:294:32)

Actually in my scss file i have simply:

```
body{
  background: black;
}
```

I would like, get the file _variable.scss and import in this all my scss file compile and put in one css file.

Comment: Where is `var content = require....`? You will need style-loader, css-loader, and sass-loader to process scss see [docs](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/blob/master/README.md#examples)

Comment: thankyou, the problem is that there isn't var content=require...